# Intel Joule 570x Expansion Board;Ubuntu 16.04;mraa;SPI not working

Tags: 16.04, intel

## Platform

Board:Intel Joule 570X Expansion Board

#### OS:

uname -a
 
Linux scout-570x-DVT3 4.4.0-1000-joule #0+joule12-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT Fri Jan 6 04:28:41 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial

#### MRAA

mraa-gpio version
Version v1.7.0-11-g47c21e0 on INTEL JOULE EXPANSION

## Question

Do I need to enable spidev for libmraa to work. If so how do I enable it?

## Program:

#### Source

```
#include "mraa.h"
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include<iostream>

int main(int argc, char** argv)<br>
{
    mraa_init();<br>
    //! [Interesting]<br>
    mraa_spi_context spi;<br>
    spi = mraa_spi_init(0);<br>
    printf("Hello, SPI initialised\n");<br>
    std::cout<<"spi init"<<std::endl;<br>
    uint8_t data[] = { 0x00, 0x32 };<br>
    uint8_t* recv;<br>
    std::cout<<"assigning  data"<<std::endl;<br>
    int i=90;<br>
    data[1] = i;<br>
    std::cout<<"spi write coming up"<<std::endl;<br>
    recv = mraa_spi_write_buf(spi, data, 2);<br>
    if (recv==NULL)<br>
        std::cout<<"error in writing"<<std::endl;<br>
   printf("Writing -%i\n", i);<br>
    //printf("RECIVED-%i-%i\n", recv[0], recv[1]);<br>
    usleep(100000);<br>
    //! [Interesting]<br>
}
```

#### Output

Hello, SPI initialised
spi init
assigning  data
spi write coming up
error in writing
Writing -90

## Debug

journalctl -t libmraa
-- Logs begin at Thu 2017-04-13 12:04:32 EDT, end at Thu 2017-06-01 18:28:10 EDT. --
Jun 01 18:18:37 scout-570x-DVT3 libmraa[2837]: libmraa version v1.7.0-11-g47c21e0 initialised by user 'scout' with EUID 1001
Jun 01 18:18:37 scout-570x-DVT3 libmraa[2837]: Adding i2c bus found on i2c-4 on adapter i2c_designware.0
Jun 01 18:18:37 scout-570x-DVT3 libmraa[2837]: Adding i2c bus found on i2c-9 on adapter i2c_designware.5
Jun 01 18:18:37 scout-570x-DVT3 libmraa[2837]: Adding i2c bus found on i2c-10 on adapter i2c_designware.6
Jun 01 18:18:37 scout-570x-DVT3 libmraa[2837]: Adding i2c bus found on i2c-5 on adapter i2c_designware.1
Jun 01 18:18:37 scout-570x-DVT3 libmraa[2837]: Adding i2c bus found on i2c-6 on adapter i2c_designware.2
Jun 01 18:18:37 scout-570x-DVT3 libmraa[2837]: libmraa initialised for platform 'INTEL JOULE EXPANSION' of type 13
**Jun 01 18:18:37 scout-570x-DVT3 libmraa[2837]: spi: Failed opening SPI Device. bus:/dev/spidev32765.0. Error 2 No such file or directory

Jun 01 18:18:37 scout-570x-DVT3 libmraa[2837]: spi: write_buf: context is invalid**

Jun 01 18:24:50 scout-570x-DVT3 libmraa[3049]: libmraa version v1.7.0-11-g47c21e0 initialised by user 'scout' with EUID 1001
Jun 01 18:24:50 scout-570x-DVT3 libmraa[3049]: Adding i2c bus found on i2c-4 on adapter i2c_designware.0
Jun 01 18:24:50 scout-570x-DVT3 libmraa[3049]: Adding i2c bus found on i2c-9 on adapter i2c_designware.5
Jun 01 18:24:50 scout-570x-DVT3 libmraa[3049]: Adding i2c bus found on i2c-10 on adapter i2c_designware.6
Jun 01 18:24:50 scout-570x-DVT3 libmraa[3049]: Adding i2c bus found on i2c-5 on adapter i2c_designware.1
Jun 01 18:24:50 scout-570x-DVT3 libmraa[3049]: Adding i2c bus found on i2c-6 on adapter i2c_designware.2
Jun 01 18:24:50 scout-570x-DVT3 libmraa[3049]: libmraa initialised for platform 'INTEL JOULE EXPANSION' of type 13
Jun 01 18:28:04 scout-570x-DVT3 libmraa[3115]: libmraa version v1.7.0-11-g47c21e0 initialised by user 'scout' with EUID 1001
Jun 01 18:28:04 scout-570x-DVT3 libmraa[3115]: Adding i2c bus found on i2c-4 on adapter i2c_designware.0
Jun 01 18:28:04 scout-570x-DVT3 libmraa[3115]: Adding i2c bus found on i2c-9 on adapter i2c_designware.5
Jun 01 18:28:04 scout-570x-DVT3 libmraa[3115]: Adding i2c bus found on i2c-10 on adapter i2c_designware.6
Jun 01 18:28:04 scout-570x-DVT3 libmraa[3115]: Adding i2c bus found on i2c-5 on adapter i2c_designware.1
Jun 01 18:28:04 scout-570x-DVT3 libmraa[3115]: Adding i2c bus found on i2c-6 on adapter i2c_designware.2
Jun 01 18:28:04 scout-570x-DVT3 libmraa[3115]: libmraa initialised for platform 'INTEL JOULE EXPANSION' of type 13
Jun 01 18:28:10 scout-570x-DVT3 libmraa[3116]: libmraa version v1.7.0-11-g47c21e0 initialised by user 'scout' with EUID 1001
Jun 01 18:28:10 scout-570x-DVT3 libmraa[3116]: Adding i2c bus found on i2c-4 on adapter i2c_designware.0
Jun 01 18:28:10 scout-570x-DVT3 libmraa[3116]: Adding i2c bus found on i2c-9 on adapter i2c_designware.5
Jun 01 18:28:10 scout-570x-DVT3 libmraa[3116]: Adding i2c bus found on i2c-10 on adapter i2c_designware.6
Jun 01 18:28:10 scout-570x-DVT3 libmraa[3116]: Adding i2c bus found on i2c-5 on adapter i2c_designware.1
Jun 01 18:28:10 scout-570x-DVT3 libmraa[3116]: Adding i2c bus found on i2c-6 on adapter i2c_designware.2
Jun 01 18:28:10 scout-570x-DVT3 libmraa[3116]: libmraa initialised for platform 'INTEL JOULE EXPANSION' of type 13

## Question

Do I need to enable spidev for libmraa to work. If so how do I enable it?